# Maintain a sorted list with performance

Tags: java, android, algorithm, list, data-structures

**Summary of my question:** I need a list that can quickly be iterated and sorted (either by sorting method or adding/removing object).

I'm coding a game in which there are a lot of "collision zones", that are checked every frame. For optimization, I have a idea of sorting them depends on their X position. The problem is not all collision zones are static, because some of them can move around.

I have managed to handles all the changes, but to maintain the `ArrayList` (or `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`) sorted using `Collections.sort()` is too slow.

So I got a new idea: I may use a Tree, and whenever a zone's X is changed, instead of sorting all elements again, I can just remove then re-add it from the tree. However, I think that adding and removing operator in TreeList are expensive too. Moreover, iterating through Tree is not as effective as `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`, `LinkedList` or `ArrayList`.

Please tell me if there is any built-in data structure that satisfy my need. If there is no such data structure, I intend to extend `ArrayList` class, override the `add` method to ensure the order (by using overload `add(index, item)`. If you think this is the best way, please give me the best way to find the index. I already use BinarySearch but I think there is a bug:

```
@Override
public boolean add(T e) {
    // Find the position
    int left = 0;
    int right = this.size() - 1;
    int pos = right / 2;
    if (e.compareTo(this.get(0)) <= 0) {
        pos = 0;
    } else if (e.compareTo(this.get(this.size() - 1)) >= 0) {
        pos = this.size();
    } else {
        // Need: e[pos - 1] <= e[pos] <= e[pos + 1] 
        boolean firstCondition = false;
        boolean secondCondition = false;

        do {
            firstCondition = this.get(pos - 1).compareTo(this.get(pos)) <= 0;
            secondCondition = this.get(pos).compareTo(this.get(pos + 1)) >= 0;

            if (!firstCondition) {
                right = pos - 1;
                pos = (left + right) / 2;
            } else if (!secondCondition) {
                left = pos + 1;
                pos = (left + right) / 2;
            }
        } while (!(firstCondition && secondCondition));
    }

    this.add(pos, e);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I take it you cannot have two collisions which can be `.equal()`? If then make your collision object implement equals()/hashCode() and Comparable efficiently and use a SortedSet.

Comment: @fge No, the comparator is performed using X position, so there may be many collision zones that have the same X position. Moreover, SortedSet is just an interface, and its Java implementation is `TreeSet`.

Comment: I know that SortedSet is an interface ;) As to comparison, you can compare on more than x, can't you?

Comment: @fge Ah I see, so if 2 X positions are equal, I can just compare two unique numbers, such as hashCode, right?

Comment: Well, hashCode is not unique by definition so I wouldn't rely on that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a tree set. if you need to allow duplicates you can use a custom comparator. while iterating a tree set is slightly slower than an array, adding and removing is much faster.

It appears you are doing an insertion sort which is O (n). an insert on a tree set is O (ln n)

IMHO The best way to store duplicates by using a `TreeMap<MyKey, List<MyType>>` like this

```
Map<MyKey, List<MyType>> map = new TreeMap<>();
// to add
MyType type = ...
MyKey key = ...
List<MyType> myTypes = map.get(key);
if (myTypes == null)
    map.put(key, myTypes = new ArrayList<>());
myTypes.add(type);

// to remove
MyType type = ...
MyKey key = ...
List<MyType> myTypes = map.get(key);
if (myTypes != null) {
    myTypes.remove(myType);
    if (myTypes.isEmpty())
        map.remove(key);
}
```

In this case, addition and removal is O(ln N);

You can allow "duplicates" is a TreeSet by defining all objects as different e.g.

```
Set<MyType> set = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<MyType>() {
   public int compare(MyType o1, MyType o2) {
      int cmp = /* compare the normal way */
      if (cmp == 0) {
          // or use System.identityHashCode()
         cmp = Integer.compare(o1.hashCode(), o2.hashCode());
         return cmp == 0 ? 1 : cmp; // returning 0 is a bad idea.
      }
   }
}
```

As you can see this approach is ugly unless you have some way of making every object unique.

Comment: Can you please give me an example how to store duplicatations? To my knowledge, a Tree can't store duplicated elements. In my case, multiple collision zones can have the same X position, so that, they meet the "equal" condition.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. I can just use a static ID number and assign (then increase) it for each object. I think in your example, to solve the "rare case" when hashCodes are equal, your approach is dangerous by just return 1?

Comment: Correct, you can use a unique id like AtomicInteger.getAndIncrement().

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to use a binary search / insert on an already sorted array or ArrayList then you will get the same big O complexity than a binary tree.

So I recommend that you actuall *test* the provided tree implementations (i.e. `TreeSet`), not just guess. As they are not plain tree implementations I would not be surprised if iteration is also fast on them.